# What's the difference between Kops and Eksctl?

Tags: kubernetes, kops, eksctl

I've searched the internet but I haven't found clear answers.

Kops is for production grade clusters and is vendor agnostic and I get that, but compared to Eksctl what are the differences ?

Also most of the articles are found are year+ old and with the speed the K8s ecosystem moves it might be outdated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`eksctl` is specifically meant to bootstrap clusters using Amazon's managed Kubernetes service (EKS). With EKS, Amazon will take responsibility for managing your Kubernetes Master Nodes (at an additional cost).

`kops` is a Kubernetes Installer. It will install kubernetes on any type of node (e.g. an amazon ec2 instance, local virtual machine). But you will be responsible for maintaining the master nodes (and the complexity that comes with that).